# Include new tables with data to existing Debezium connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, debezium

Objective:

Need to add a new table to existing Debezium MySQL connector version 1.1.1.Final. The data from the table should be populated to the topic after the connector restart with updated configs(new tables in the *table.whitelist*).

Problem:

There is no clear strategy to add a new table(s) which will be added to the Kafka with its data after the initial snapshot was taken (the previous version of the connector is working). We are looking for something similar to *snapshot.select.statement.overrides* only for the working connector. *snapshot.select.statement.overrides* doesn't work when the snapshot is already created and the connector is restarted with new tables.

Possible solution:

Create and run new connector for tables which should be initialized with data(*snapshot.mode=initial*). Disadvantage: every release *may* include a new connector.

OR

1. Create migration connector(v2) for the tables (with configs *snapshot.mode=initial* and new *database.history.kafka.topic*)
2. Delete connector v2 after snapshotting completed
3. Remove *database.history.kafka.topic* for the previous connector(v1)
4. Update connector(v1) one with tables from the connector(v2) - put them to *table.whitelist*
5. Change *snapshot.mode* to *schema_only_recovery* and start the connector(v1)

Question:

Which way is official? Maybe am I missing something and there is more easiest way than the second?

**UPD:**
Per @Matar comment and some investigation, it looks like no need to remove *database.history.kafka.topic* because, in the default configuration, it collects all DDL from the DB anyway.

Comment: I'm working on something similar to your task in hand (MSSQL). I went with solution (2). I just wonder why would you create a new database.history.kafka.topic ? can't I just use that one from V1 since all tables belong to same DB.

Comment: @matar I think, you are right. No need to recreate the topic again especially if you use your connector is listening to all changes in the DB. I am wondering that Debezium doesn't support upgrade scenario yet after years.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of Debezium Server, you can add the following config value

```
debezium.snapshot.new.tables=parallel
```

In case If you are using Debezium, you can try this config value

```
snapshot.new.tables=parallel
```

Note: Debeziyum Server is the one that supports Kinesis, Google Pub sub, and Apache Pulsar. I am using that and its configuration is a bit different. I had to prepend "debezium" before each item

Once this configuration is added, any addition to tables.whitelist, For these additional tables Debezium will create snapshots.